# How do you use ravendb facets with the http api?

Tags: ravendb

I am using the http api (no .net) to use raven.

I can't find any documentation regarding using facets directly using the http api.

If you have done this before then please answer with a brief overview of urls and json required to setup and query a facet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is fairly simple.

First of all define the facet, to do this simply save the facet as a document in the database with the id facets/[your-facet-name]

A facet document looks like this:

```
{
  "Facets": [
    {
      "Mode": "Default",
      "Name": "type",
      "Ranges": []
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more about the options for the Facet object [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/1.0/client-api/faceted-search)

Now assuming you have already setup an index called my-index you can use the facet by getting the url:

/databases/[your-database-name]/facets/[your-index-name]/facetDoc=facets/[your-facet-name]&query=[your-query]

The query is the normal lucene query format you would use when querying an index.

As it happens most of this information is already on the [facets page](http://ravendb.net/docs/1.0/client-api/faceted-search) you just have to read it closely!

Comment: Good find!  Thanks for the detail.  Perhaps you would be willing to write a page on facets for the http documentation?  Fork and submit pull requests to: https://github.com/ravendb/docs